# Use of undeclared identifier 'sender' in void function

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am doing a custom `Segue` on `Storyboard` and I have a button that contains this code:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"line3" sender:sender];
```

By clicking on the button it works well. The problem I am running into that this code only works inside a button function not inside a void function. I tried clicking on the button and it works well. When I paste it inside just a void function it gives me an error complaining about the sender. I tried changing it to void but nothing happens. Can you give me some insight on to fix this issue. I am checking a `UserDefault` and it matches what I am looking for then I want to to perform this code: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"line3" sender:sender];`

```
-(IBAction)LoginAttemp:(id)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"line3" sender:sender];
}



-(void) LoginFailed{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"line3" sender:sender];
}
```

**Error I Get:**

> Use of undeclared identifier 'sender'

Any insight?

Comment: show more code, a button, IBAction is the same thing as void, so something else must be different...

Comment: I added the code for the button and the void function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"line3" sender:sender];
```

to

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"line3" sender:Nil];
```

the sender is:

> The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is
>   made available for informational purposes during the actual segue.

Comment: yeah that works too, the sender in this case is for informational purposes.

Comment: Got it to work with Nil for some reason self never worked for me, even before the post. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`void` isn't the issue. The issue is that `sender` is not a reserved word. It's one of the parameters to your `IBAction`:

```
-(IBAction)LoginAttemp:(id)sender{
```

See? Right there at the end. That's Objective-C equivalent of `IBAction LoginAttemp(id sender)`

If you don't have a sender, you can pass `nil` or `self`. Using `self` would be preferred.

```
-(void) LoginFailed{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"line3" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me why "self" is preferred over "nil"?

Comment: Apple describes the sender as: "The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue." `nil` is not explicitly disallowed, but neither is it explicitly allowed. My preference is to provide some context in case I need to know "who" invoked the segue.